# How to correctly make side effects during rendering on functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I read [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178) that side effects should go to `useEffect`, but that immediately prevents me from calling hooks inside `useEffect` because of the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

> Side effects go into a different place (lifecycle methods in classes,
>   or useEffect in function components)

However, it seems to me rather common that a `Child` triggers a function on its `Parent`, for example, a `onClick` from a child's `Button`. That `onClick` on the other hand, may have side effects, like changing the `Parent`'s state, which can have a side effect on the rendering of both the Parent and Child.

Calling these methods "naively" only gave me the error "Cannot update a component (`Parent`) while rendering a different component (`Child`)", although my goal here is not to solve that error but get a general knowledge on how to apply side effects during rendering.

Here's an example of side effects during rendering. I couldn't reproduce that error so I'm not sure if this approach is right, is it?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type ButtonProps = {
    color: string;
    onClick: (newCounterValue: number) => void;
};

function Button({ color, onClick }: ButtonProps) {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    return (
        <span style={{ backgroundColor: color }} onClick={() => {
                setCounter(counter + 1);
                onClick(counter + 1);
            }}
        >
            Increase counter </span>
    );
}

function App() {
    const [shouldShowGreen, setShouldShowGreen] = useState(true);
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    return (
        <div>
            <span>Counter value: {counter}</span>
            <Button color={shouldShowGreen ? `green` : `blue`}
                onClick={(newCounterValue: number) => {
                    setShouldShowGreen(newCounterValue % 2 === 0);
                    setCounter(newCounterValue);
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with a quick code example of where this is causing you issues? Your understanding of side effects, hooks, and passing state up seems to be correct but it sounds like the implementation/structure of what you're trying to do is causing the issues.

If your onClick on the child component is changing local state (of the child component) as well as the parent state, then yes, you're probably going to get some issues with the parent state change "resetting" the child component.

Comment: That's exactly my situation: my `onClick` changes the local state (child's state), and calls `onClick()` that was passed from the parent to the child. The OnClick also changes the parent's state, and I get the error. How to aviod that?
I'll try to reproduce the error  later on a smaller project to avoid unnecessary code on the question.

Comment: Hey, @jsrgnt, I added the `Button` example on my question. The `onClick` in the child has side effects on both the child and the parent, although it did not raise an Error on my tests. For some reason it still appears to me that this not the right way to deal with side effects, based on the sources in my question...

Comment: I think your example is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

## The example code in your question does not perform a side effect in render.

Both components, `App` and `Button`, call `useState` and then return a value. Neither of these cause side effects that we need to worry about.

The rendered value does contain event handlers that do perform side-effects, but they are not actually called during render. For example this function will only be called when a button is clicked and not during render:

```
() => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    onClick(counter + 1);
}
```

However, if you had assigned that function to a variable and then called it before returning within the component body, that would give you trouble. For example, this component will cause the error you're seeing:

```
function Button({ color, onClick }: ButtonProps) {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
        onClick(counter + 1);
    }
    handleClick(); // Don't do this!
    return (
        <span style={{ backgroundColor: color }} onClick={handleClick}
        >
            Increase counter </span>
    );
}
```